# SSDT reference msdb system tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I have a view which references system tables of msdb database. I tried adding extracting msdb database's data-tier and add msdb as reference in SSDT project. However, it looks like it is still not able to access msdb database's system table. It is able to access non-system tables though.

View Definition:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vGetData]
AS
SELECT * FROM dbo.BackupData d
INNER JOIN
[$(msdb)]..backupfile AS b ON b.backup_set_id = d.backup_set_id
```

Is there anyway I can fix it? Alternatively, is there any way to exclude this view from compile list so SSDT does not report any error for this (but still includes it in the deployment)?

Comment: To add references to system databases, right-click the References folder, choose "Add Database Reference" and then pick "system database" (`master` and `msdb` are the choices). Manually extracting things will not work correctly. Also, make sure to properly qualify objects: `msdb.dbo.backupfile`, do not rely on the default schema.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I suggest you post you comment as an answer.